# Nonlinear root finding in numpy from two complex equations

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy

Why it does not calculate properly?
Correct solution is c=25.672 and b2=10.24.
Here solver returns the input values.
Thanks for help!

```
from numpy import *
from scipy.optimize import *

#UNITS:
psi = 6895.
ft=0.3048
inch=0.0254
psisqin=psi*sqrt(inch)

#DATA:
K_Ict=1500.*psisqin
K_Icb=1700.*psisqin
sigma_2=6700.*psi
sigma_1=6000.*psi
sigma_3=7200.*psi
hp=105.*ft
P = 6500*psi

def f(p):
    b2,c= p
    F1 =  sqrt(pi*c)*(K_Icb-K_Ict)/2 - ( (sigma_2-sigma_1)*sqrt(c**2-b2**2) - (sigma_3-sigma_1)*sqrt(c**2-(hp-b2)**2) )
    F2 =  sqrt(pi)*(K_Icb+K_Ict)/(2*sqrt(c)) - ( (sigma_2-sigma_1)*arcsin(b2/c) + (sigma_3-sigma_1)*arcsin((hp-b2)/c) - (sigma_2+sigma_3-2*P)*pi/2 )
    return (F1,F2)

b2, c =  fsolve(f,(16.002,30))
print b2, c
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why but I think it's because you are leaving one of the roots out of the range, so it just returns the boundaries you gave. The true reason depends on whatever method is using to find the roots. The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) states:

> fsolve is a wrapper around MINPACK’s hybrd and hybrj algorithms.

These algorithms are a bit beyond my expertise but you'll find documentation about them easily. This [link](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~more/ANL8074b.pdf) is one example.

In any case if you change the boundaries to contain both your roots you should obtain the correct results (within a tolerance):

```
from numpy import *
from scipy.optimize import *

#UNITS:
psi = 6895.
ft=0.3048
inch=0.0254
psisqin=psi*sqrt(inch)

#DATA:
K_Ict=1500*psisqin
K_Icb=1700*psisqin
sigma_2=6700*psi
sigma_1=6000*psi
sigma_3=7200*psi
hp=105.*ft
P = 6500*psi

def f(p):
    b2,c= p
    F1 =  sqrt(pi*c)*(K_Icb-K_Ict)/2
    F1 =  sqrt(pi*c)*(K_Icb-K_Ict)/2 - ( (sigma_2-sigma_1)*sqrt(c**2-b2**2) - (sigma_3-sigma_1)*sqrt(c**2-(hp-b2)**2) )
    F2 =  sqrt(pi)*(K_Icb+K_Ict)/(2*sqrt(c)) - ( (sigma_2-sigma_1)*arcsin(b2/c) + (sigma_3-sigma_1)*arcsin((hp-b2)/c) - (sigma_2+sigma_3-2*P)*pi/2 )
    return (F1,F2)

b2, c =  fsolve(f,(9.002,30))
print(b2, c)
```

This results in:

```
10.2613616029 25.63857432
```